# Table Manipulations in Excel VBA

Tags: database, vba, excel, data-manipulation

I have the following table on one sheet, top table of the picture, and I need to transform it to the to the different format on the second sheet (bottom table of the picture). I need to use VBA in Excel to do this manipulations. I pulled the main table (top) from SQL query on the separate sheet and need to rearrange it to fit my needs. I have a lot more data than that but it follows the same format. Just imagine that there are just more Shelves, Items, Amounts and Stores.

I searched everywhere but can't seem to find direct answer.

I am relatively new to VBA. Can someone give me a some directions? Is there a website with some tutorials about table manipulations in Excel VBA?

[image: Table_Link_Image]

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond an intellectual pursuit, there is absolutely no need for VBA. From your example, put this *array formula* in C24.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$23, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($B$2:$B$23), COUNTIF($B24:B24, $B$2:$B$23), 1), 0)), "")
```

Finalize with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered correctly, fill right until you run out of values to retrieve.

In A25 use this *standard formula*.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$24:A24, MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, MAX(A$2:A$23))+1)<SUMPRODUCT((D$2:D$23<>"")/COUNTIF(D$2:D$23, D$2:D$23&"")), MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, MAX(A$2:A$23))+1, "")
```

Fill down to get all of the shelves you will need.

In B25 use this *array formula*,

```
=IF(AND(ROW(1:1)>1,COUNTIF(A$24:A25, A25)=COUNTIF(A$24:A24, A24)), B24, IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$23, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($D$2:$D$23), COUNTIF(B$24:B24, $D$2:$D$23), 1), 0)), ""))
```

Finalize with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Fill down to catch all of the stores.

Finally, put this in C25.

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$23, $A$2:$A$23, $A25, $B$2:$B$23, C$24, $D$2:$D$23, $B25)
```

Fill right to D25 then fill C25:D25 down to the length of the table.

[image: Store Inventory Tables]

The only difference in my second table is that *Water* comes before *Gartorade* and that is a result of it appearing the first table's *Item* list first.

Comment: I am running a VBA script to get data from the SQL table on another sheet. I am using a Micro button to update the information. Is there a way to implement this in VBA?

Comment: @KevinP - FWIW, a couple of GROUP BY aggregates in your SQL SELECT statement should be sufficient to put it into exactly what you are trying to achieve.